# Do acid derivatives (anhydrides/amides/acyl halides) give positive Iodoform test?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Technically, having a methyl carbonyl group should enable them to give positive Iodoform test.

Comment: They don't give iodoform test. The reason is the decreased electrophilicity of the carbonyl carbon can't lead to the end of the reaction.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74315/does-acetamide-respond-positively-to-iodoform-test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does acetic acid give a positive result with the iodoform test?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47495/does-acetic-acid-give-a-positive-result-with-the-iodoform-test)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does acetamide respond positively to iodoform test?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74315/does-acetamide-respond-positively-to-iodoform-test)